# Restart Service with non-root user

Tags: linux, apache, web-services, service, ubuntu-14.04

I am using UBUNTU-14.04 LTS

I want to restart service with non-root user.

My change in visudo file for Apache service,

## User privilege specification

root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

username ALL=/etc/init.d/apache2

username ALL=NOPASSWD: /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

But it's not working

**Output :**

```
Restart with **non-root user**

/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
 * Restarting web server apache2      [fail]

Restart with **root user**

/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
 * Restarting web server apache2      [ OK ]
```

Waiting for a positive response.

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Try "sudo service apache2 restart" or "sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/192050/how-to-run-sudo-command-with-no-password

Comment: XXXXX@XXXXX-desktop:~$ sudo service apache2 restart
[sudo] password for root: 
XXXXX@XXXXX-desktop:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
[sudo] password for root:

Comment: Did you change /etc/sudoers as on manual above?

Comment: Only add that 2 line under User privilege specification, nothing more.

Comment: Thanks Max for helping me, I got solution.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried putting your user in a group and giving him the rights for all the files?

This should add (existing) userA to groupA and give him the rights to directoryA

```
sudo usermod -a -G groupA userA

sudo chown -R userA:groupA directoryA
```

Hope this helps